# Python unit testing issue with mock patch dict os env variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

```
@mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"CONTAINER": "TrUe"}, clear=True)
def test_use_container_true(self):
    """
    Test the env var for if a containers should be used or not.
    """
    self.assertEqual(a.__container__, True, "not returning python bool True")

@mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"CONTAINER": "fAlSE"}, clear=True)
def test_use_container_false(self):
    """
    Test the env var for if a containers should be used or not.
    """
    self.assertEqual(a.__container__, False, "not returning python bool False")
```

Here is the code it is testing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

env_container = os.getenv('CONTAINER')
if env_container is None:
    __container__ = False
else:
    env_container = env_container.lower()
    if env_container == 'true':
        __container__ = True
    else:
        __container__ = False
```

I get this error:

```
F......
======================================================================
FAIL: test_use_container_false (test_amadla.TestGlobalVars)
Test the env var for if a containers should be used or not.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py", line 1768, in _inner
    return f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/user/Projects/SiteNetSoft/Amadla/AmadlaToolServerImageBuilder/test_amadla.py", line 57, in test_use_container_false
    self.assertEqual(a.__container__, False, "not returning python bool False")
AssertionError: True != False : not returning python bool False

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 10 tests in 0.002s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

It seems it keeps the value `True`.

Is it taking the value from mock as it is supposed to do?

Comment: What _is_ `a`? And why are you making up a dunder attribute?

Comment: I used it to make it more readable. But I'll change it since it is not standard. The issue remains... no?

Comment: Make what more readable? Without a [mre] it's hard to say, it's unclear what the issue is.

Comment: What's processing the string `"TrUe"` into a Boolean value `True`?

Comment: In the Mock I am setting the env var as false so it should be equal to false. But the value is still true.

Comment: What code sets `a.__container__` based on the string value of `CONTAINER`?

Comment: I added the code that it is testing.

Comment: Mocking `os.environ` does not change the value `os.getenv` will return.

Comment: FYI that could just be `__container__ = os.getenv("CONTAINER", "false").lower() == "true"`

Comment: How are you creating the object `a` in your tests? Could it be that the `__container__` value is not getting set for each test? Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is difficult to know.